# MySQL New Value of Column A by Comparing Current Year vs. Previous Year (Column B)

Tags: mysql, comparison

I have a MySQL table with two columns, Column A and Column B.

Column A is distinct product ID# and Column B represents Year.

I want to compare current year with previous year to see which product is new and didn't sell in the previous year.

How can I do this?

So for a table like below, what query can I put to select the records with Year 2013 and Product ID CC since CC does not appear in 2012.

```
+-------------+------------+
| Year        | Product ID |
+-------------+------------+ 
| 2012        | AA         |
| 2012        | BB         |
| 2013        | AA         |
| 2013        | BB         |
| 2013        | CC         |
+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Why not call them id and year instead of columna and columnb

Comment: You were right. Thanks for your quick fix on displaying table.

Comment: Great. So now you can go back and remove every reference to columns a and b. Then, consider expanding your data set and desired result to make them more representative. For instance, what if C sold in 2011? Finally, and most importantly, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple select statement that will allow you to search for the ProductID of an item where the year corresponding to that id is 2017.

```
SELECT Product ID
FROM Table
WHERE Product ID = 'CC' AND Year = 2013;
```

will return the correct result for you.

If the year represents the year the product was added, I don't see why you would need to compare it to other years, versus just searching that year specifically.

Comment: I want to select new product ID from the year 2017 only by comparing with these of the year 2016.

Comment: Is PRODUCTID and YEAR a composite key? If not, you will only be able to have a product ID listed once, regardless of year. If they are a composite key, is it possible that you only want to see if an item is being reintroduced after not being sold in the previous year, but may have been sold in years prior to that?

Comment: To simplify the question, I just want to compare the current year with previous year.

Comment: So for a table like below, what query can I put to select the records with Year 2013 and Product ID CC since CC does not appear in 2012.

| Year        | Product ID |
| ------------- |-------------| 
| 2012      | AA |
| 2012      | BB |
| 2013      | AA |
| 2013      | BB |
| 2013      | CC |